# Is ProxyCreationEnabled = false is equal to AsNoTracking() in Entity framework?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Is ProxyCreationEnabled = false is equal to AsNoTracking() in Entity framework?

And we can use AsNoTracking() in table level. but how to use AsNoTracking() in stored procedures.

Comment: The results of stored procedures are not tracked, you don't need an `AsNoTracking()` option

Comment: What method of calling SP do you have in mind - e.g. `DbSet.SqlQuery`, `Database.SqlQuery` or?

Comment: In my case I want increase the performance of my api service. As of now for get methods I have used AsNoTracking() with table for retrieving data from DB. So shall I Include "ProxyCreationEnabled = false" also to improve the performance or not required.And I have used some SP's in entity framework.How to improve the performance of web api which has Entity SP to retrieve the data from DB

Answer (score 3):

Proxies and tracking are two different, but combinable concepts.

**Proxies** generate a derived class at runtime for advanced features like lazy loading, property changed, etc. While proxies are usually coupled with a tracking context, the don't necessarily have to.

**Tracking** indicates whether or not your open context saves a reference to the returned object and is able to detect changes to it. It can do this with or without proxies. Without proxies the context "simply compares" all tracked references to their initial state when you call `Save()`.

Comment: Hi Tozantron, Thanks for the update. In my case I want increase the performance of my api service. As of now for get methods I have used AsNoTracking() with table for retrieving data from DB. So shall I Include "ProxyCreationEnabled = false" also to improve the performance or not required.And I have used some SP's in entity framework.How to improve the performance of web api which has Entity SP to retrieve the data from DB.

Comment: For performance there a many different factors. Disabling proxies helps, but it is also important to look at your queries and data structure. Loading only required properties with `new {}` is faster than loading the entire enity, filter as much as possible on the Db and sometimes even denormalizing the tables can help.